# java console output not printing in shell script

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I am working on a shell script where i will call a jar file.

When i execute the shell script the i get a return code 1 from call to java. Also console output jar file is not printed in the terminal

```
javaArgs="-jar $baseRoot/lib/preprocess.jar"
javaCmd="java $javaArgs \"$filePath1\" \"$filePath2\"";
echo $javaCmd
$javaCmd
recode=$?
echo $recode
```

**output**

[Exec From Shell Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcz5Q.png)

When i directly run the jar file in terminal i got the expected output and also do not get warnings.

```
java -jar /shelldir/lib/preprocess.jar "/shelldir/data/file1.txt" "/shelldir/data/file1.xml"
```

How to get the console output of jar file when running from shell script ?

Addtional Info: I am executing the shell script from putty bash terminal.
EDIT: I use log4j in jar and build my jar using maven-shade-plugin and maven-jar-plugin to specify classpath. The conf folder mentioned in the below pom has the log4j.properties file

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.file.PreProcessor</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                            <outputFile>lib/preprocess.jar</outputFile>
                            <!-- <outputDirectory>target\maven-shade</outputDirectory> -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Command: mvn jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>../conf/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultEntries>true</addDefaultEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <!-- <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**log4j.properties**

```
#define the console appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# now define the layout for the appender
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.traceLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.traceLog.MaxFileSize=30MB
log4j.appender.traceLog.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.traceLog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.traceLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.infoLog=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infoLog.MaxFileSize=30MB
log4j.appender.infoLog.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.infoLog.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.infoLog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infoLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1} %x - %m%n

# now map our console appender as a root logger, means all log messages will go to this appender
log4j.rootLogger = TRACE, infoLog,traceLog
```

Comment: Do read about tee command.

Comment: Could you provide your input from shell script?
It is not clear what is wrong as script looks correct. The only - semicolon in second string is not needed, but it is not an error, just useless.

Comment: @Saboteur Added More info

Comment: Removing the double quotes from the argument make the code work fine. But what if there is a space in any of the argument. since my args are file paths. I will try it and update here

Comment: When my args contain space it did not work 
`Invalid Arguments. Please verify the input arguments` and return code is 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
javaArgs="-jar $baseRoot/lib/preprocess.jar"
javaCmd="java $javaArgs \"$filePath1\" \"$filePath2\"";
echo $javaCmd
echo $($javaCmd)
recode=$?
echo $recode
```

Comment: I tried the above code, i get `$recode` as 0 but jar did not succeed (same as before).